# Disable scroll in jquery mobile when page loader appears

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I need to disable touch and scroll when my loader appears in jquerymobile phonegap application.I am opening a loader on an Html element and using loader CSS class.

```
.loaderCont {
background-color:  rgba(255,255,255, 0.99);
height: 81%;
width:  100%;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: -1;
overflow:hidden;
margin-top: 20%;

}
```

here is my loader class.[image]
Here is my Loader.I can scroll background content while scrolling on loader.
I just need to stop this.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the progress screen in javascript you can disable the scroll action and re-enable it once the progress screen is hidden. For this you can use the below:

To Disable scrolling:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', scrollHandler);

function scrollHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

To enable scrolling again:

```
document.removeEventListener('touchmove', scrollHandler);
```